# Is there anyway to change the database server without stopping the database?

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I have a database in data center, which is running MySQL, and I want to change the database from data center to host in my company. At that time, I don't want to stop the data base in the data center, is there anyway to this kind of integeration? Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Replicating:**

You can setup a **MySQL replicate** database at your host. It will start replicating the data from the "old" database server into your new one asynchronously while the application is running. 
[image]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/images/redundancy-before.png))</sub>

**Swapping:** Afterwards you can switch the application to write to the new database.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/images/redundancy-after.png))</sub>

Swapping a master MySQL with a slave MySQL replicate: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-switch.html

MySQL Replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

You could setup the new Mysql server as replication slav and then switch the connection in your application from the old to the new server.